# Send a user's text input to a database to update

Tags: textinput, visual-c#-express-2010, sql-server-2008r2-express

Pretty new here. But before I ask my question, I'm not looking for "teh codez". I just want to know how one would go about doing this.

I have some regular HTML textboxes in a web page, and I want to know how I would go about taking that input (ofcourse, textbox has special ID and so does the submit button), and submitting it to a database.
I'm using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, and SQLserver 2008 R2 express as my database. Someone suggested using c#, but what methods would I use in C#? Throw me some methods, please?

HTML inputs

```
<span class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon-disk ui-icon saveButton" title="Save" style="float:left"></span><input type="text" class="lace" id="march"/><br />
<span class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon-disk ui-icon saveButton" title="Save" style="float:left"></span><input type="text" class="lace" id="march2"/><br />
<span class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon-disk ui-icon saveButton" title="Save" style="float:left"></span><input type="text" class="lace" id="march3"/><br />
```

---

Everything above this HR is the previous question asked here..
 To be more specific, I've looked through all the tutorials in the answer i've okayed..
To be more specific, What I'm trying to accomplish is this..

I have these textboxes, SQL server 2008 R2eXpress, and VisualWebDeveloper 2010eXpress.
These text boxes are to show the original value from the database when the page loads.. But the user is able to update them. Once they change the content in these textboxes, they hit submit, and it sends it to the database to update the table that the information is sitting in..
Again, not really looking for "teh codez", but just solid methods or tutorials I could look at that will help me achieve what i'm trying to do.
*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways you can go.

If you're using "Web forms", the answer is entirely DIFFERENT from the one you're implictly asking.  I definitely encourage you to look at web forms.  There are many tutorials, including this one:

- http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/tailspin-spyworks/tailspin-spyworks-part-1

However, you're asking about simple CGI:

- Write some HTML
- Put some  tags, usually including a "submit" button in a "form" tag
- Provide a CGI "action" handler on the server to receive the input

Here's a good example on how to do this with C#:

http://chalaki.com/8-steps-program-install-setup-call-csharp-cgi-programs-in-iis-7/321/

Yet a third possibility is to do your processing on the client side: using Javascript (or a Javascript framework like jQuery or Dojo) running on the client's browser.

Comment: This looks promising.. Thanks for the advice: )

Comment: This is an awesome tutorial and explained exactly what I was trying to do. Worked good for me, and it's very descriptive for the C# n00b.
http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson01